# Inheritance of $scope object in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS. I am confused about the inheritance of $scope object. Like i hope $scope object is specific to a controller. How it inherits values to the other controllers. Code below is taken from official documentation

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example9-production</title>
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>    
</head>
<body ng-app="scopeInheritance">
  <div class="spicy">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
      <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

      <div ng-controller="GrandChildController">
        <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
      </div>

        <div ng-controller="GrandChildController2">
        <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### App.js

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('scopeInheritance', []);
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'morning';
  $scope.name = 'Nikki';
}]);
myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.timeOfDay = 'morning2';
  $scope.name = 'Mattie';
}]);
myApp.controller('GrandChildController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'evening';
  $scope.name = 'Gingerbread Baby';
}]);
myApp.controller('GrandChildController2', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
})(window.angular);
```

The GrandChildController2 controller did not change the name and timeOfDay property of `$scope` object. I expect the output should be like 
`timeOfDay ='evening'` and `name = 'Gingerbread Baby'` if it inherits from parent. But surprisingly the output of `GrandChildController2` controller is      `timeOfDay ='Good morning2'` and `name ='Mattie'`. How is this possible?

Could you please explain

Thanks
Manivannan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can you see in the following schema `GrandChildController` and `GrandChildController2` are brothers and both sons of `ChildController` (as the their name suggests).

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
  |
  |-- <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>       <!-- Good morning, Nikki'! -->
  |
  |   <!-- inherits from MainController and then overwrite -->
  |-- <div ng-controller="ChildController">
      |-- <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>   <!-- Good morning2, Mattie! -->
      |
      |   <!-- inherits from ChildController and then overwrite -->
      |-- <div ng-controller="GrandChildController">
      |     <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p> <!-- Good evening, Gingerbread Baby! -->
      |-- </div>
      |
      |   <!-- inherits from ChildController and does NOT overwrite -->
      |-- <div ng-controller="GrandChildController2">
      |     <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p> <!-- Good morning2, Mattie! -->
      |-- </div>
      |
  |-- </div>  <!-- CLOSE ChildController -->
  </div>  <!-- CLOSE MainController -->
```

So `GrandChildController2` inherits the `$scope` from its parent `ChildController` with `$scope.timeOfDay = 'morning2'` and `$scope.name = 'Mattie'`.

**WHAT YOU EXPECTED**

To obtain the behaviour you expected (`GrandChild2` inherits from `GrandChild`) the schema has to be like this:

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
  |
  |-- <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>       <!-- Good morning, Nikki'! -->
  |
  |   <!-- inherits from MainController and then overwrite -->
  |-- <div ng-controller="ChildController">
      |-- <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>   <!-- Good morning2, Mattie! -->
      |
      |   <!-- inherits from ChildController and then overwrite -->
      |-- <div ng-controller="GrandChildController">
          |-- <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p> <!-- Good evening, Gingerbread Baby! -->
          |
          |   <!-- inherits from GrandChildController and does NOT overwrite -->
          |-- <div ng-controller="GrandChildController2">
          |     <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p> <!-- Good evening, Gingerbread Baby! -->
          |-- </div>
          |
      |-- </div>  <!-- CLOSE GrandChildController -->
  |-- </div> <!-- CLOSE ChildController -->
  </div> <!-- CLOSE MainController -->
```

Comment: Now I understand.. Thank you so much @GsusRecovery

Answer (score 0):

`GrandChildController2` is inheriting from `ChildController` so that's the reason for the output.

Maybe the formatting mislead you?

Comment: Hi @sirrocco.. Thanks for you reply but i don't understand how you are saying GrandChildController2 is inheriting from ChildController ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `</div>` for `ChildController`. So, it is considering that scope values.

**Try this:**

```
    <body ng-app="scopeInheritance">
  <div class="spicy">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
      <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

      <div ng-controller="GrandChildController">
        <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>     

        <div ng-controller="GrandChildController2">
        <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```